# What's the meaning of "dump" in the context of "adrenaline dump"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of the *noun* "**dump**" in the context of "[**adrenaline dump**](http://www.bjjweekly.com/blog/post/managing-adrenaline-dumps)"?

> It’s an **adrenaline dump**, nature’s way of preparing my body for fight
>   or flight. And it can be very difficult to control or deal with. The
>   primal nature of a grappling competition (after all, we are literally
>   getting ready to try and choke someone unconscious) amplifies the
>   bodies’ reaction. My hands are literally twitching a little bit as I
>   type this, just visualizing the moments before a match begins.

I checked dictionaries and I don't understand what meaning of the **noun** to choose between the ones that exist there. ([Cambridge dictionary- dump](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dump?q=DUMP). [Oxford dictionary- dump](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dump))

Comment: My first thought was that [*adrenaline **pump***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22adrenaline+pump%22) would make a lot more sense here. I was quite surprised to find that the 2250 hits for that in Google Books was only marginally greater than the 2130 hits for [*adrenaline **dump***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22adrenaline+dump%22), which strikes me as a rather curious collocation for *any* context. But there are twice as many (>900) hits for the alternative spelling ***adrenalin pump***.

Comment: But, "dump" and "pump" would have very different meanings here.  This adrenaline dump means something like an adrenaline *flood* -- it's a large and sudden release of adrenaline.  This noun phrase refers to the action of dumping adrenaline, not some device which transports adrenaline.

Comment: I upvoted Glorfindel's answer but it would be good to know what the antecedent of it is here. In this type of context, "antecedent is everything".

Comment: to many the a. rush is the release, the a. dump is the fall in adrenalin after the cause of the rush goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both dictionaries have an entry for the *verb* 'to dump' which applies here:

> 1.2 Put (something) down heavily or carelessly.
>   ‘she dumped her knapsack on the floor’

(Oxford)

> C2 to put down or drop something in a careless way:
>   He came in with four shopping bags and dumped them on the table.

(Cambridge)

Your brain instructs the [adrenal glands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenal_gland) to release a rather large amount of adrenaline to your body (greatly increasing the level) and doesn't care how the body reacts to it.

Comment: Thank you. Both in the verbs definitions. No one in the noun definitions. How could you explain it?

Comment: English often 'nouns' verbs and vice versa: http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/verbing-weirds-language-but-in-a-good-way

Comment: Thank you very much. I learnt something you today.

Comment: So regards to our words "adrenaline dump" it means that the adrenaline quantities is decreased?

Comment: No, it's actually greatly *in*creased in your body.

Comment: Then I am sorry but I really don't understand the relation between "put down" and increasing.

Comment: @Perplexedfolks The adrenal gland will _dump_ a load of adrenaline into the blood stream (not sure whether the gland stores it, or makes it on demand: that's for a biologist!). Compare with "_he came home and dumped the shopping on the table_"... in both cases, there's now an increased amount of "the thing" (adrenaline/shopping) lying around.

Comment: Just compare the adrenaline dosis with the four shopping bags. They're produced somewhere in your body, of course, and the 'dump' is the act of releasing the adrenaline from these organs into your entire body.

Comment: You might want to add the release or discard idea to your excellent answer.

Comment: Thank you - but that's already covered in Andrew's answer, I guess?

Answer (score 2):

To add on to Glorfindel's answer:

"Dump" has an underlying meaning

> to release, store, or discard a large quantity of something

related to [these definitions from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dump)

> 3 : to sell in quantity at a very low price, specifically : to sell abroad at less than the market price at home
>
> 4 : to copy (data in a computer's internal storage) to an external storage or output device

Definition 3 describes the action of *releasing* a large quantity of a product into a particular market at a drastically reduced price.  This forces the competition to also lower their prices, possibly below the point where they can sustain their business.  Through this practice an unscrupulous manufacturer might take a short-term business loss in order to capture a monopoly on a particular market.  It's called "dumping" because the products are sold in large quantities, (since small amounts would have no effect).

Definition 4 describes the *storage* of a relatively large amount of "raw" data related to some computer process. Because raw data is not filtered in any way before the "dump", it needs to be parsed afterward to find anything relevant.  For example, Facebook might to a "dump" of the logs of all user activity over a certain period of time, which can then be separately analyzed to find particular patterns or locate one significant record.

In a similar way, an "adrenal dump" means that the gland releases a significant quantity of the hormone in response to a particular stimulus.  The use of "dump" implies that the release is somewhat *unregulated* in quantity -- that the gland simply releases as much as it can.

Answer (score 1):

I find both dictionaries' noun definitions needlessly restrictive, but perhaps this reflects a difference in U.S. versus U.K. usage. To look at a couple of American dictionaries, [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dump) provides the definition

> An unordered accumulation; a pile.

and [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dump) says

> an accumulation of refuse and discarded materials

In short, a *dump* is any release of something en masse. A database dump, for instance, is a download of the entire contents of a database, rather than a curated query that chooses specific rows and columns. This connotation is perhaps reinforced by the stateside usage of terms like *dump truck*, which apparently is known as a *tipper* elsewhere.

[image: Dump truck (US) or tipper lorry (UK)]

This is the origin of computing terms like *core dump* and *database dump*, which are requests for the entire contents of something rather than a curated query for specific data, and of the concept of [dumping](https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/adp_e/adp_info_e.htm) in international trade, where a market is flooded with imported goods to damage domestic suppliers.